# HTML5 JavaScript Pasting Image Data in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, tinymce, coffeescript

How do I develop a working example using this plugin: [HTML5 JavaScript Pasting Image Data in Chrome](http://strd6.com/2011/09/html5-javascript-pasting-image-data-in-chrome/)

The author has put together a great example that seems like it would suit our purposes. I'm not familiar with creating a jQuery plugin however.

The goal will be to use this plugin to paste clipboard images into a rich text editor such as TinyMCE.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>PASTE IMAGE</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Created by STRd6
// MIT License
// jquery.paste_image_reader.js
(function($) {
var defaults;

  $.event.fix = (function(originalFix) {
    return function(event) {
      event = originalFix.apply(this, arguments);
     if (event.type.indexOf('copy') === 0 || event.type.indexOf('paste') === 0) {
        event.clipboardData = event.originalEvent.clipboardData;
     }
  return event;
};
})($.event.fix);

defaults = {
  callback: $.noop,
  matchType: /image.*/
};

$.fn.pasteImageReader = function(options) {
if (typeof options === "function") {
options = {
    callback: options
  };
}

options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

return this.each(function() {
  var $this, element;
  element = this;
  $this = $(this);

  $this.bind('paste', function(event) {
    var clipboardData, found;
    found = false;
    clipboardData = event.clipboardData;

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(clipboardData.types, function(type, i) {
      var file, reader;
      if (found) {
        return;
      }

      if (!type.match(options.matchType)) {
        return;
      }

      file = clipboardData.items[i].getAsFile();
      reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function(evt) {
        options.callback.call(element, {
          filename: file.name,
          dataURL: evt.target.result
        });
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      found = true;
    });
  });
});
 };
 })(jQuery);


$("html").pasteImageReader (results) -> 
    {filename, dataURL} = results

$("body").css
    backgroundImage: "url(#{dataURL})"

</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm confused by the plugin call:

```
$("html").pasteImageReader (results) -> 
    {filename, dataURL} = results

$("body").css
    backgroundImage: "url(#{dataURL})"
```

That doesn't look like jQuery that I've seen. Is it specific to the plugin itself? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Last code _plugin call_ isn't a JavaScript, so it's not a jQuery. Answer is in the plugin code.

Comment: Its CoffeeScript - and since CoffeeScript compiles to Javascript, it IS jQuery. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those last calls are in CoffeeScript, a language that compiles into JavaScript. (http://coffeescript.org)

```
$("html").pasteImageReader (results) -> 
    {filename, dataURL} = results

$("body").css
    backgroundImage: "url(#{dataURL})"
```

Im no expert - in fact i've never used coffeescript at all - but It would compile to:

```
$("html").pasteImageReader(function(results) {
  var dataURL, filename;
  return filename = results.filename, dataURL = results.dataURL, results;
});

$("body").css({
  backgroundImage: "url(" + dataURL + ")"
});
```

That would probably work, but I dont like how its formatted. Here's some cleaner code.

```
$("html").pasteImageReader(function(result){
     $("body").css({backgroundImage: "url("+result.dataURL+")"});
});
```

Give that a shot, and see if you can make it work for you!

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is correct, in that the calls are in CoffeeScript and simply need to be converted, but note that those calls are just part of a demo and all they do is change the background of the page to be whatever was pasted from the user's clipboard. If you want to paste into a rich text editor, you need something more along these lines:

```
$("#yourRichTextEditor").pasteImageReader(function(results) {
  document.execCommand("insertimage", 0, results.dataURL);
});
```

This assumes that your text editor is working with a `contentEditable`-enabled element, like a `div`, with an ID of `yourRichTextEditor`; and that whatever browser this is running in supports the [`contentEditable` command](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla) `insertimage`. I'm using [Bootstrap-Wysiwyg](http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/) on a project where I call the `pasteImageReader` plugin with the above code, but presumably it should work for most if not all HTML5-based rich text editors.